# how does processor come to know that IRQ or FIQ occur and how it changes to a specific interrupt request mode ?

Tags: arm, interrupts

Suppose processor is in user mode and IRQ occur then its changes to IRQ mode.

But user mode does't have write access to control field of cpsr then how the mode is changed ?
May be i am wrong, Please explain.

ARCH = ARM.

Thanks in Advance.

Answer (score 0):

The interrupt actually *interrupts* the user mode code and changes the processor to IRQ mode. That's why it's called an interrupt. The hardware can do anything, and the interrupt mechanism is implemented in the hardware.

Comment: To change the mode control field of CPSR should be set but in user mode there is no write permission on cpsr. then how mode is getting changed. this is regarding to ARM.

Comment: The hardware has permission to do whatever it wants, and interrupts are implemented in hardware.